# Numerical puzzle

Tags: calculation-puzzle

A friend of mine sent me this puzzle, to solve it you need to use:

1) basic arithmetic operations.

2) Multiple numeral systems.

[image]

Comment: What is an appropriate solution? Find the bold characters values?